# numpy division with RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, warnings

I wrote the following script:

```py
import numpy

d = numpy.array([[1089, 1093]])
e = numpy.array([[1000, 4443]])
answer = numpy.exp(-3 * d)
answer1 = numpy.exp(-3 * e)
res = answer.sum()/answer1.sum()
```

But I got this result and with the error occurred:

```
nan
C:\Users\Desktop\test.py:16: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  res = answer.sum()/answer1.sum()
```

It seems to be that the input element were too small that python turned them to be zeros, but indeed the division has its result.

How to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can't solve it. Simply `answer1.sum()==0`, and you can't perform a division by zero.

This happens because `answer1` is the exponential of 2 very large, negative numbers, so that the result is rounded to zero.

`nan` is returned in this case because of the division by zero.

Now to solve your problem you could:

- go for a library for high-precision mathematics, like [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/). But that's less fun.
- as an alternative to a bigger weapon, do some math manipulation, as detailed below.
- go for a tailored `scipy/numpy` function that does exactly what you want! Check out @Warren Weckesser answer.

Here I explain how to do some math manipulation that helps on this problem. We have that for the numerator:

```
exp(-x)+exp(-y) = exp(log(exp(-x)+exp(-y)))
                = exp(log(exp(-x)*[1+exp(-y+x)]))
                = exp(log(exp(-x) + log(1+exp(-y+x)))
                = exp(-x + log(1+exp(-y+x)))
```

where above `x=3* 1089` and `y=3* 1093`. Now, the argument of this exponential is

`-x + log(1+exp(-y+x)) = -x + 6.1441934777474324e-06`

For the denominator you could proceed similarly but obtain that `log(1+exp(-z+k))` is already rounded to `0`, so that the argument of the exponential function at the denominator is simply rounded to `-z=-3000`. You then have that your result is

```
exp(-x + log(1+exp(-y+x)))/exp(-z) = exp(-x+z+log(1+exp(-y+x)) 
                                   = exp(-266.99999385580668)
```

which is already extremely close to the result that you would get if you were to keep only the 2 leading terms (i.e. the first number `1089` in the numerator and the first number `1000` at the denominator):

```
exp(3*(1089-1000))=exp(-267)
```

For the sake of it, let's see how close we are from the solution of Wolfram alpha ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B%28exp%5B-3*1089%5D%2Bexp%5B-3*1093%5D%29%2F%28%5Bexp%5B-3*1000%5D%2Bexp%5B-3*4443%5D%29%5D)):

```
Log[(exp[-3*1089]+exp[-3*1093])/([exp[-3*1000]+exp[-3*4443])] -> -266.999993855806522267194565420933791813296828742310997510523
```

The difference between this number and the exponent above is `+1.7053025658242404e-13`, so the approximation we made at the denominator was fine.

The final result is

```
'exp(-266.99999385580668) = 1.1050349147204485e-116
```

From wolfram alpha is ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28exp%5B-3*1089%5D%2Bexp%5B-3*1093%5D%29%2F%28%5Bexp%5B-3*1000%5D%2Bexp%5B-3*4443%5D%29))

```
1.105034914720621496.. × 10^-116 # Wolfram alpha.
```

and again, it is safe to use numpy here too.

Comment: But in this case I need to get values of the division by 2 very small values.

Comment: @Heinz I think you meant the case in which a small number is divided by a small number. In that case change your algorithm to scale both numbers up is much better than finding mechanical twists. For example, take logarithm of the analytical equations that your code is trying to simulate.

There are many issues with stability of computation when small numbers are involved. It's nicer to avoid having any of them if possible.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`np.logaddexp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) (which implements the idea in @gg349's answer):

```
In [33]: d = np.array([[1089, 1093]])

In [34]: e = np.array([[1000, 4443]])

In [35]: log_res = np.logaddexp(-3*d[0,0], -3*d[0,1]) - np.logaddexp(-3*e[0,0], -3*e[0,1])

In [36]: log_res
Out[36]: -266.99999385580668

In [37]: res = exp(log_res)

In [38]: res
Out[38]: 1.1050349147204485e-116
```

Or you can use [`scipy.special.logsumexp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html):

```
In [52]: from scipy.special import logsumexp

In [53]: res = np.exp(logsumexp(-3*d) - logsumexp(-3*e))

In [54]: res
Out[54]: 1.1050349147204485e-116
```

Answer (score 1):

This warning also occurs if a zero-length (in some dimension) array is passed to a numpy method that uses division to derive its output (e.g. `np.mean()`, `np.median()`, `np.var`, `np.cov`, etc.).

A common way to get such array is to filter an array using some condition which returns a zero-length array. So if this warning is raised even though you're not working with very small or very large numbers, check the shape of the array.

An example:

```py
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr_sliced = arr[arr < 0]   # array([], dtype=int32)
avg = np.mean(arr_sliced)   # RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the order of z,y,x rather than x,y,z:
see the code

```
# one point and w,h ROI creating
x, y = 400, 300
w, h = 50, 80
roi_mask = np.zeros_like(stacked_volume)      # create same size all-zero tensor
roi_mask[:, y:y+h, x:x+w] = 1       # note: the order is Z, Y, X
# roi_mask[x:x+w, y:y+h, :] = 1     # this will make the error
```