# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars in python

Tags: python

I run this code but always get this error -

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

I can't find what is the error in my code:

```
from numpy import zeros
def eliminasi_gauss(A,b):
n=len(A)
C=zeros((n,n+1))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        C[i,j]=A[i,j]
    for i in range(0,n):
        C[i,n]=b[i,0]
    for k in range(0,n-1):
        if C[k,k]==0:
            for s in range (0,n+1):
                v=C[k,s]
                u=C[k+1,s]
                C[k,s]=u
                C[k+1,s]=v
        for j in range (k+1,n):
            m=C[j,k]/C[k,k]
            for i in range(0,n+1):
                C[j,i]=C[j,i]-m*C[k,i]
            X = zeros((n,1))
X[n-1,0]=C[n-1,n]/C[n-1,n-1]
for j in range(n-2,-1,-1):
    S=0
    for i in range(j+1,n):
        S=S+C[j,i]*X[i,0]
        X[j,0]=(C[j,n]-S)/C[j,j]
return X
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy division with RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double\_scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784528/numpy-division-with-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars)

Comment: Your indentation is bad, so that code would not run at all. Please edit the code to be that which gave the error you show. Also, show the complete traceback for the error and the code that sets up the parameter values and calls your function. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you devided by zero. But for more details check the [numpy.seterr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) function to get more information about where the RuntimeWarning happens.