# Problemm calculating a summation

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate a summation as part of a class assignment to develop a code for the gradient method. The summation is the objective function off which I need to find the minimum. Calculating the summation I get this error  "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars  `y = y + (-0.01*i + exp(-(1/x1)*((u - x2)**x3))**2)`".

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
x1 = 1
x2 = 50
x3 = 1
def f(x1,x2,x3): 
    y = 0
    for i in range(1,100):
        u = (25+(-50*log(0.01*i))**(2/3))
        print(u)
        y = y + (-0.01*i + exp(-(1/x1)*((u - x2)**x3))**2)


        print(f'y{i} : {y}')
    return y

y1 = f(25,50,1.25)
y2 = f(26,51,2.25)


print(f'y1: {y1}')
print(f'y2: {y2}')
```

Comment: When asking a question you should put the full error traceback in your question, there are hidden clues as to what's wrong in the traceback.

Comment: Thank you @Hoog . I added the full error message.

Comment: You might find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784528/numpy-division-with-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a cast in `u`, see:

```
u = float((25+(-50*log(0.01*i))**(2/3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few passes through your loop, you are trying to raise a negative number to a non-integer power.  I added a few print statements to figure out what is up, right before the warning you have `(u - x2) = -0.6175251618426216` and `x3 = 1.25`.  Raising a negative number to a fractional power will give a complex number as a result, which numpy assumes you don't want and so it thrown a warning and returns `None`.  You can tell numpy to use complex numbers by type casting one of your inputs to `complex`:

```
from numpy import *
x1 = 1
x2 = 50
x3 = 1
def f(x1,x2,x3): 
    y = 0
    for i in range(1,100):
        u = (25+(-50*log(0.01*i))**(2/3))
        print("u:",u)
        print("y:",y)
        print("x1:",x1)
        print("x2:",x2)
        print("x3:",x3)
        print("calc:",(complex(u - x2)))
        y = y + (-0.01*i + exp(-(1/x1)*(complex(u - x2)**x3))**2)


        #print(f'y{i} : {y}')
    return y

y1 = f(25,50,1.25)
y2 = f(26,51,2.25)


print(f'y1: {y1}')
print(f'y2: {y2}')
```

This will give results as complex numbers, you'll need to check with your theory how to handle this (probably by taking either the magnitude or the real part).