# Solving Shrodinger's equation for a particle in a harmonic potential well

Tags: python, numpy

Hello (this is my first time posting in stack overflow), I am trying the calculate the first 3 energy levels of a particle in a harmonic potential using the shooter method

The code is adapted from a script in Computational Physics by Mark Newman, this script calculated the ground state for a particle in a box.

here is the link http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cp/programs/squarewell.py

here is my adapted code

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.constants import m_e,hbar,elementary_charge

#define constants

vo = 50
a = 1e-11

#define limits of integration for adaptive runge-kutta method

xi = -10*a
xf = 10*a
N = 1000
dx = (xf-xi)/N

def V(x):#define harmonic potential well
    return vo*((x**2)/(a**2))

def f(r,x,E): #schrodinger's equation
    psi = r[0]
    phi = r[1]
    fpsi = psi
    fphi = (2*m_e/(hbar**2))*(V(x)-E)*psi
    return np.array([fpsi,fphi],float)

def solve(E): #calculates wave function for an energy E
    psi = 0.0
    phi = 1.0
    r = np.array([psi,phi],float)
    for x in np.arange(xi,xf,dx): #adaptive runge-kutta method
        k1 = dx*f(r,x,E)
        k2 = dx*f(r+0.5*k1,x+0.5*dx,E)
        k3 = dx*f(r+0.5*k2,x+0.5*dx,E)
        k4 = dx*f(r+k3,x+dx,E)
        r += (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
    return r[0]

#finds the energy using secant method

E1 = 0.0
E2 = elementary_charge
psi2 = solve(E1)
target = elementary_charge/1000

while abs(E1-E2)>target:
    psi1,psi2 = psi2,solve(E2)
    E1,E2 = E2,E2-psi2*(E2-E1)/(psi2-psi1)
    print (E2/elementary_charge)
```

when run I get this error

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

E1,E2 = E2,E2-psi2*(E2-E1)/(psi2-psi1)
```

which I think means that psi2 and psi1 are too close together but I am not quite sure how to fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy division with RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double\_scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784528/numpy-division-with-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! You are right about the values being too close to each other. Your code returns a `nan`. It is because of the division by zero.

I would suggest using a correction factor. Something like `max(delta, (psi2-psi1))` in the denominator where `delta` can still be a very small value but it will prevent the `division by zero`.

Comment: thanks! I no longer get the error, but now I just get back 1.0, after some tried it seems that whatever initial value I put in for E2 is the ouput so would the `max(delta, (psi2-psi1))` stop the E2 value from being updated?

Comment: What delta value are you using now?

Comment: i was trying with very small numbers like 1e-11

Comment: But after investigating it seems that the solve(E) function outputs the same result regardless of what I set E to, I tried with numbers ranging from 1 to 10000 and it produced the same result, so in the while loop both psi1 and psi2 are being updated with new results from the solve(E) function but the results are the same so E2 ends up being infinity, E1 is nan and the loop stops

Comment: I'd recommend printing out all values from k1 through k4 and also r, in the for loop itself to see if the values are as expected. And then debug from there.