# How can I get rid of this warning? (RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars)

Tags: python, pandas

## Solved it

Used `n = np.divide(number1, number2)`

And checked `if number2 > 0` before dividing

---

I have this code:

```
condition5 = round(((df['Close'][-1] - df['Low'][-1])/(df['High'][-1] - df['Low'][-1])),2) < 0.25
```

**df** is a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
                  High         Low        Open       Close      Volume   Adj Close
Date                                                                              
2019-11-20  266.079987  260.399994  265.540009  263.190002  26558600.0  263.190002
2019-11-21  264.010010  261.179993  263.690002  262.010010  30348800.0  262.010010
2019-11-22  263.179993  260.839996  262.589996  261.779999  16331300.0  261.779999
2019-11-25  266.440002  262.519989  262.709991  266.369995  21005100.0  266.369995
2019-11-26  267.160004  262.500000  266.940002  264.290009  26301900.0  264.290009
```

And the message I get is:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  condition5 = round(((df['Close'][-1] - df['Low'][-1])/(df['High'][-1] - df['Low'][-1])),2) < 0.25
```

I don't get it, I have used print() to see the values and there wasn't anything weird nor any warning message popped up.

I have also checked 
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784528/numpy-division-with-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars)
and the response says you can not get rid of it.

Other links in stackoverflow suggest its a division by zero which is not true because It's not possible to have High - Low = 0.

***UPDATE:***

**print(df['High'][-1] - df['Low'][-1])**

```
4.660003662109375
```

**print(df.to_dict())**

```
{'High': {Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'): 263.17999267578125, Timestamp('2019-11-25 00:00:00'): 266.44000244140625, Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'): 267.1600036621094}, 'Low': {Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'): 260.
8399963378906, Timestamp('2019-11-25 00:00:00'): 262.5199890136719, Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'): 262.5}, 'Open': {Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'): 262.5899963378906, Timestamp('2019-11-25 00:00:00'): 262.70999145
50781, Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'): 266.94000244140625}, 'Close': {Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'): 261.7799987792969, Timestamp('2019-11-25 00:00:00'): 266.3699951171875, Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'): 264.29
00085449219}, 'Volume': {Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'): 16331300, Timestamp('2019-11-25 00:00:00'): 21005100, Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'): 26301900}, 'Adj Close': {Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'): 261.77999877
92969, Timestamp('2019-11-25 00:00:00'): 266.3699951171875, Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'): 264.2900085449219}}
```

**print(df.info())**

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3 entries, 2019-11-22 to 2019-11-26
Data columns (total 6 columns):
High         3 non-null float64
Low          3 non-null float64
Open         3 non-null float64
Close        3 non-null float64
Volume       3 non-null int64
Adj Close    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 168.0 bytes
None
```

Comment: Could you please check the output of the following:

`df['High'][-1] - df['Low'][-1]` and report the smallest, largest values in this dataframe.

Comment: Is `Date` index? Do you mind to share `print(df.to_dict())`?

Comment: Do you mind to post the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: shared all those prints in the UPDATE section