# Gradient descent algorithm retruns nan values for b0 and b1

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient descent algoritm and it is retruning nan for b0 and b1

```
def Gradient_Descent(x,y,epochs,learning_rate,b0=0,b1=0,):
  for i in range(epochs):
    n=float(len(x))
    yhat=b0+b1*x
    b0_grad=(-2/n)*sum(y-yhat)
    b1_grad=(-2/n)*sum(x*(y-yhat))
    b0=b0-learning_rate*b0_grad
    b1=b1-learning_rate*b1_grad
  return b0,b1
```

```
Gradient_Descent(x,y,1000,0.00001)
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  
(nan, nan)
```

Comment: What is n? Are accidentally dividing by zero?

Comment: I think there are nan values in your x and/or y arrays. The function itself runs fine for me with some mockup data.

Comment: @ JoostVn  There are no nan values in x and y, I checked with pd.isnan(). Can you try with my this data https://github.com/MA2932/LinearRegression_Scikit/blob/main/Data/GPA-SAT.csv

Comment: @Otto Kässi n is the number of records it is not 0. I am getting output for a really low learning rate '''Gradient_Descent(x,y,1000,0.0000001)'''  but  it is not the right value (1.148553038683468e-06, 0.0018042675296552377)

Comment: Maybe this discussion helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784528/numpy-division-with-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars